# Return directory listing 2 levels down if applicable using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to return a list of files found in a specified directory. I am accomplishing this with following code:

```
public List<String> getDirectoryListing(String urlPath)throws{
    InitParams ip = new InitParams();
    Elements links;
    List<String> directoryListing = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://" + urlPath).get();

        links = doc.select("body a");
        for (Element link : links){                 
            directoryListing.add(link.text());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return directoryListing;
}
```

However, I have different case, where there could be another folder inside this one with the file in it.

I need to check if what this returns is a directory and if that is the case, go inside of it and return the file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need some recursive logic in there, in which the method calls itself to list files in subfolders.  It will then go as many levels deep as you need.  You'll need a more complex object than string which can hold children.  I'd make your own class.

**pseudo code, something like this, this is not compilable, but it relays the algorithm**

```
public List<WebFile> getFiles(urlPath) {
    List webFiles = new web files list;

    List urlFilesList = methodToGetWebFilesList(urlPath);
    foreach urlFile in urlFiles {  
       //constructor has logic to parse whatever is in URL file and 
       //determine if it is a director
       WebFile webFile = new WebFile(urlFile);

       if "webFile" is a directory  {
         //recursive call to self, drill down into this file
         children = getFiles(urlFile);
         webFile.children.addAll(children);
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great idea @slambeth

```
public List<String> getDirectoryListing(String urlPath)throws Exception
        {
            return getDirectoryListing(urlPath, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        public List<String> getDirectoryListing(String urlPath, List<String> directoryListing)throws Exception
        {
            InitParams ip = new InitParams();
            Elements links;

            try
            {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://" + urlPath).get();

                links = doc.select("body a");
                for (Element link : links)
                {
                    if(link.text().lastIndexOf("/")>0) {
                        getDirectoryListing(urlPath + link.text(), directoryListing);
                    }
                    else
                        directoryListing.add(link.text());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return directoryListing;
        }
```